# How to perform lambda in clause to remove all matching records based on supplied statecodes list

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
string countryname = "India";
var StateCodes = ("012","016","15","11") // fetched data from database table

_EFContext.OfficeTbl.RemoveRange(_EFContext.OfficeTbl.Where(so =>so.country == countryname && so.State in StateCodes)));
```

achieved this using foreach loop but failed to do in lambda appropriately,
plz suggest/guide !
thanks!

Comment: Ideally, you fetch the statecodes in the **same database action** where you use them... either via sql `NOT IN()`, exclusion join, or `NOT EXISTS()` operations. How the looks from entity framework, I'm not sure.

Comment: actually that i'm getting from an api call which interects with diff db

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `StateCodes` is some sort of a collection, you can do it like this (other code is skipped for simplicity):

```
_EFContext.OfficeTbl.Where(so =>so.country == countryname 
                           && StateCodes.Any(z => z == so.State))
```